# Linking to OpenCV under MacOSX

Tags: c++, macos, linker, opencv

I'm trying to compile a C++/OpenCV Code in MacOS X Snow Leopard which was originally under Linux. I installed OpenCV 2.2 using MacPorts, but I cannot use something like this anymore:

```
g++ -o Localization Localization.o DataReader.o Kalman.o -libopencv_core -libopencv_highgui -L/usr/local/lib/
```

I'm getting this error:

```
ld: library not found for -libopencv_core
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Localization] Error 1
```

I tried other variations; like -lcv, -lhighgui which I originally used to use, but I'm not sure what to use here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The link flag should be `-lopencv_core` not `-libopencv_core`. The latter will look for a file called `libibopencv_core.{dylib,a}` instead of `libopencv_core.{dylib,a}`. The same for `opencv_highgui`.

Comment: 1. is wrong. http://codepad.org/Lfp6nEFC (also, this is osx, so .dylib instead of .so)

Comment: @etarion You are right, sorry. Just looked up `man ld`. The extension is of no worry, though.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using macports, you're using the wrong paths. It should be `-L/opt/local/lib`, not `/usr/local`. Also, to make things easier, you should just use pkg-config:

```
g++ -o Localization Localization.o DataReader.o Kalman.o $(pkg-config --libs opencv)
```

(that assumes that you have `/opt/local/bin` in your `PATH`). This way you can use the same line for linux and OS X.

Comment: it works on OSX Darwin 15.6.0 Darwin Kernel Version 15.6.0 as of 2018